# mi formulario reactivo no actualiza valores recividos desde un servicio

Tags: angular

tengo un un elemento tipo cliente en un servicio,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y un componente que tiene un formulario y que implementa formulario reactivo con formBuilder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi problema es que al momento de ingresarle un nuevo valor a clientEdit(el servicio) desde otro componente, el valor en el "editForm" (el FormGroup), no actualiza su valor, ya comprobe que el nuevo valor llegue al componente, pero FormGroup por algun motivo no actualiza al nuevo valor, se queda con el valor inicial que tenia el servicio que es null. si le coloco algun otro valor inicial al servicio, toma ese valor pero despues ya no vuelve a actualizar.

pdt: se puede agregar el valor directo en el html con "[value]", pero de ese modo el valor se muestra en el html pero el FormGroup no lo toma como valor, sigue teniendo el valor inicial null. recien cuendo agrego o quito un caracter en el input el formGroup toma el valor entero del input.

pdt2: es un formulario para editar informacion, por eso necesito que la informacion vaya cambiando segun el cliente que se elija.

me podrian ayudar con una idea de como realizar la actualizacion desde el ts. Gracias

Comment: Saludos @WilderSalinas, primero que nada te pediría por favor que [edites tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/584374/edit) y **pegues** el código como texto en lugar de ponerlo como imagen y segundo tal vez ayudaría si también agregas el código html del formulario. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrias usar ngOnChange() y la clase  ChangeDetectorRef para poder detectar los cambios en el componente y obligar a pintar el nuevo cambio en el dom.
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef